# trying to do this simple function with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

So I'm making a function that basically checks if the string past the 0th element is an exclamation mark and the first element is the letter 'h'.

so example:

```
>>>f('h!')
True
>>>f('h!!!!!')
True
>>>f('!!!!!')
False
>>>f('!!!h')
False
```

i wanted to do this using list comprehension but i end up making the output a list with the first element being the truth value. My function is the following:

```
def f(s):
  return s[0] == 'h' and [i == '!' for i in s[1:]]

this returns
  >>>f('h!!')
  [True]
```

What's wrong with the way i've done it? if i remove the brackets after the 'and', it raises a syntax error.

Comment: It's easy with other methods: **RegEx**: `re.match('h!+', s)`. **String replace**: `s[0]=='h' and s.replace('!','')=='h'`. Why do you need to use list comprehension?

Comment: I don't need to use list comprehension but i wanted to do it for practice. thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 3):

Try printing the *list comprehension* part:

```
print [i == '!' for i in s[1:]]
```

you will get a list of booleans like

```
>>> [True, True, True]
```

So if you want to apply the AND operator (returns `True` if all the elements are `True`) to that list (so you get the correct result), you can use the [**`all()`**](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#all) built-in function:

```
return s[0] == 'h' and all([i == '!' for i in s[1:]])
```

According to Python docs:

> **all(iterable)**: Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty).

**Edit:**

As @thefourtheye commented, to avoid the list creation, you can pass a generator expression to `all()`:

```
return s[0] == 'h' and all(i == '!' for i in s[1:])
```

Comment: You can pass a genexp to `all`, no need to create a list.

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
s[0] == 'h' and all(i == '!' for i in s[1:])
```

`all` returns True if all the elements of the generator expression inside are returning True.

Comment: You can also use `str.startswith`.

Comment: @user3050527 `all` takes an iterable (like a list) and returns true if all of its elements are true

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the fastest way

```
def f(s):
  return s == "h" + "!" * (len(s) - 1)
```